# capture/trace custom request header - iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webbrowser-control, iis-logs

I would like to capture URL requested and its sequence. And also like to know resources (.JS,.CSS and images) requested for each page.

one option is to use IIS logs. but here i am not able to bind resources with page requested.

since my web pages are been loaded in desktop application. i can add custom request header say "SequenceId" which will be incremented on each page request and in IE 8  additional header are proporgated to request header of resources.

But in IIS 6.0 we are not able to capture additional header on server-side using IIS Log.

i am aware of IIS 7.0 Advance logging where we can get it. but we are using IIS 6.0 web server.

Can anyone help me out ? is there any other better way to solve it?

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to take a look at HTTP handlers. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090(v=VS.90).aspx